# How can I reliably find the OneDrive directory path, so that I can allow user to write file to it

Tags: .net, wpf, onedrive

This seems like it should be so simple.  Currently, I am "finding" this by iterating through the Quick Access entries for one marked "OneDrive" and getting the path.  Looks like another way is to get the environment variable "OneDrive".

I have a little editor, and I'd like the user to be able to save the file "to the cloud".  It occurred to me that an easy way to do this is to just save it to the OneDrive folder, and let the sync thing do it's thing.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OneDriveConsumer")` or `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OneDriveCommercial")` should give a reliable path depending on whether you have one or several OneDrive clients on your machine.

Comment: I tried both of those environment variables, go the folder path on "OneDriveConsumer" (and, for reference, got same path using "OneDrive", thanks @Jazimov,  and null on "OneDriveCommercial".  Which seems right.

Comment: So then you're obviously using a single OneDrive client. What's your current issue?

Comment: With this tidbit, I don't really have an issue any more...  Oh, I guess I forgot to mark as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the reserved `%onedrive%` environment variable that points to the OneDrive path for the currently logged-on user. Is there anything stopping you from using this?

Comment: anything stopping me?  only this -- fear... that it will change someday.